# remote access without portforward

Tags: vpn

i do have a silly question that i got stuck with.
i have some machines in some remote places that gets moved around different networks.
the systems do get Internet access from the LANs router and an IP of 192.168.x.x
i would like to ask if there is any trick to have the machines always seen from me.
i do not have the privilege to change the IP of the system since it is changed up to the user's satisfaction and i do not know the static IP of the router. Also portforwarding is not not possible. 
i thought of openvpn or pptp these machines to be the clients and my box to be the server, but the clients IP changes all the time and i cannot access them to alter the config.
I do need to have access to these machines as part of monitoring and support. 
is there a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an external, reachable machine where you can ssh to make the link. I used a [iPad app that allowed this for windows machines](http://jumpdesktop.com/free-remote-desktop.html) using the google servers; I tried to find/adapt the solution to forward a VNC connection to my linux desktops without success.

If you have an external machine where you can do `ssh`, you can make a reverse tunnel; suppose you have the hidden machine named "hidden", running the ssh daemon, and the external machine called "hub", also running ssh daemon; you can on `hidden` do (this should be in a script automatically started, checking for failure and restarting, etc.)

```
ssh -e none -R 2222:localhost:22 hub
```

and then connecting to `hub` with

```
ssh hub -p 2222
```

your connection will be tunneled to `hidden`. You can change port 22 to 5900 to forward for example VNC (Desktop) connections.

Obviously, you need to reach `hub` --- its port 2222 should be opened. Otherwise, if `hub` has just port 22 (standard ssh) open, you can ssh into `hub` and there do

```
ssh localhost -p 2222
```

and you are again forwarded to `hidden`.